# How to Stretch Background images on tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

So I have done research, but the solutions I've found aren't working. I'm using the Fluid Neue theme, and I want to make the background image stretch for high resolution screens. It's not a problem for me since I use a 720p monitor, and the images mostly fits, however, I've been told that the BG image is only in the upper left corner on higher resolutions like 1080p.

I've tried the background-size: cover trick, but it's not working. I'm not sure if it's because I'm putting it in the wrong place of the HTML or what. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to post some code, but I do have an idea that should work.

Answer (score 0):

how is this:

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/7eLM5/

I added a wrapper div for all my content and set the following properties:

```
#wrapperBG {
   background:url("http://slackwise.cfmldeveloper.com/images/bg/bat.jpg") no-repeat;
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   left:0;
   background-size:cover;
}
```